# How to save groups as separate assets with layers prefixed in the filename

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting

I am trying to save illustrator art assets using the inbuilt Layer/Group hierarchy to determine the save location and file name. I believe this requires some Illustrator script.

---

In this case I have a hierarchy as follows:

Layer → Sublayer → Group → Paths

The group level objects are the desired art assets. I would like to save files at the group stage grouped by folders such that each asset is nested in a folder with the name of its parent and grandparent giving a file directory that would read:

```
Layer/Sublayer/Group.png
```

Furthermore, I would like the name of the group's parent to be able to be prefixed to the art assets file name, giving a file directory that would
instead read:

```
Layer/Sublayer/Sublayer_Group.png
```

---

The asset export tool does not appear to have this functionality.

I have included an example of the desired results below.

[image: Illustrator Hierarchy]

[image: Desired folder structure - inside the layer folder]

[image: Desired folder structure and first filename option - inside the sublayer folder]

[image]